# Scrollable Flot Chart

Tags: javascript, flot

I have a flot chart that is a nice line chart. Currently, if you click and drag over the chart, it will select the dragged-over area and when you let up the mouse, it will zoom into the selection. What I want, is for that behavior, but to then put a scrollbar under the chart that lets me scroll through the data at the current zoom level. What I am looking for here is the general way to hook into Flot that allows me to define what part of the data is currently visible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check out the [navigation plugin](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/navigate.html) which allows panning and zooming.

The example there lets you pan using a compass arrow interface, but there is no reason you couldn't use something like a scroll bar instead.

Comment: Finally found the function in the code for the navigation plugin (`plot.pan`), thanks!